The length of the trajectory of an object trying to reach another object on movement but the object is unable the predict the trajectory of the second
Statement:
On a plane, we have three points, A, B, and C. Point A is the starting point of object a, and point B is the starting point of object b. Object a travels at a higher speed than object b such that:
_ > _​. Point C is the destination point of object b, where  = ∞. Object b moves from B towards C (point C only defines the trajectory of object b). A, B, and C are not aligned. We know angle ABC, length AB, and the ratio 
, where  = _/_. Object a aims to meet object b but is unable to predict the trajectory of object b. The question is: How to find the distance traveled by object a before crossing object b for >1 (given: ,  ).
My reasoning:
Let's define point O as the intersection point of the bisector of ABC and the line perpendicular to (AB) passing through A. Let D_O be the point where (BC) tangentially intersects the circle centered at O with radius AO. We have _ =  and  = _. The distance AO is expressed as follows:  = tan⁡(/2) × . Let's denote ¤as the length of the arc of circle _ with center O. To find ¤, we need to know the angle _, which is expressed as follows: =2arctan⁡(/). Now we can find the length ¤ : ¤ = (2/360)×_. Let _ be the speed associated with the ratio ¤/_.
_ confirms that if / = ¤/_, then object a will travel a distance ¤ before meeting object b at point D_O. However, _ may be different from .
Consider a point R belonging to the line (AO) placed downstream of O such that  > . We associate this point with speed _>_. Let's assume _ = . Using a simple cross-product, we have:  ↔  and  ↔ _ : = ( × _) / _.
My reasoning stops here because I cannot find the angle _, where _ is the intersection point between (AB) and the circle with radius AR and center R.
According to me, the distance traveled by a for all  ≥ _ is the arc of circle _ with radius  ( × ) /  and center R.
Thank you for helping me with the resolution of my problem ;)

I believe you are looking for a specific pursuit curve called a radiodrome.  The wikipedia article has an equation for the intersection point and the equation of the curve which you could then integrate to find the distance.
